# how to convert mysql query into mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have using cakephp Mysql to Mongo db query component that is convent mysql query into mongodb, but when query have multiple parentheses then code has stop working, i have also try to convert query on http://www.querymongo.com/ site the same issue show up,

```
SELECT * FROM `matches` WHERE (
( user_id = "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" AND partner_user_id = "55094c30156b049809000004" ) OR
( user_id = "55094c30156b049809000004" AND partner_user_id = "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" ) OR 
( doublz_partner_id_a = "55094c30156b049809000004" AND doublz_partner_id_b = "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" ) OR 
( doublz_partner_id_a = "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" AND doublz_partner_id_b = "55094c30156b049809000004" ) 
)
```

can you please help me convert this query into mogodb, i am newbie in mongodb

Comment: @ThomasBormans Apparently nothing other than use SQL to MongoDB sites that do not provode correct results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations on making no effort whatsoever to look at documentation and solve this. Perhaps your "site" should do better as well:

```js
db.matches.find({
    "$or": [
        { 
            "user_id": "550aa8b6156b046c09000000", 
            "partner_id": "55094c30156b049809000004" 
        },
        { 
            "user_id": "55094c30156b049809000004", 
            "partner_id": "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" 
        },
        { 
            "doublz_partner_id_a": "55094c30156b049809000004", 
            "doublz_partner_id_b": "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" 
        },
        { 
            "doublz_partner_id_a": "550aa8b6156b046c09000000", 
            "doublz_partner_id_b": "55094c30156b049809000004" 
        }
    ]
})
```

It's how you structure an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query as stated in the documentation.

By the way, "thanks for helping me" is your response.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.matches.find({"$or": [
        { 
            "user_id" : "550aa8b6156b046c09000000", 
            "partner_id" : "55094c30156b049809000004" 
        },
        { 
            "user_id" : "55094c30156b049809000004", 
            "partner_id": "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" 
        },
        { 
            "doublz_partner_id_a" : "55094c30156b049809000004", 
            "doublz_partner_id_b" : "550aa8b6156b046c09000000" 
        },
        { 
            "doublz_partner_id_a" : "550aa8b6156b046c09000000", 
            "doublz_partner_id_b" : "55094c30156b049809000004" 
        }
    ]
})
```